# How to "output" / "reproduce" "blank lines" (stored in the database) in a rendered view file?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, text

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know how to "output" / "reproduce" "blank lines" (stored in a database column Type TEXT) in a rendered view file. That is, in my database column Type TEXT I have stored the following data (*note*: blank lines are really the ones present in the data):

```
Line 1
Line 2

Line 3


Line 4
...
```

*In order to make the outputted text* (in front-end content) *to "follows" / "reflects"* "*spaces*" (for the above case) *accordingly to data stored in the database*, for example, I would like to output some HTML code as like the following:

```
Line 1<br/>
Line 2<br/><br/>
Line 3<br/><br/><br/>
Line 4
...
```

... or something else that makes that I would like to accomplish.

In other words, **I need some formatting of raw database data to be outputted as much as possible like HTML code would be**. How it is possible in a *correct* and *not dangerous* (for example, there may be problems related to Cross-Site Request Forgery - CSRF) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need any formatting other than your newlines then you could use a [`<pre>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/pre.html):

```
<pre><%= your_text %></pre>
```

The `<%= %>` will take care of HTML encoding everything and the `<pre>` will take care of formatting your line breaks.

Comment: I need some formatting of database data to be outputted as-like HTML code would be. I updated the question with more details.

Comment: @user12882: So the text is already HTML? And you didn't whitelist it before putting it in your database?

Comment: The text stored in the database is not HTML. It is just plain text.